# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in asp.net with the try trans_rollback

Tags: asp.net

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
public void Trans_Rollback()
{
   trans.Rollback();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you disposed 'trans' or 'con' variable (or both) before calling 'TransRollback()'.
If you're using NHibernate, take a look to the querying part. If you use **using** statement with any of these variables you need to call your rollback method before statement parenthesis closes, since it means disposing object **using** were used with.
If that's not your case - provide more information, maybe at least framework you're using for accessing database. And context you calling your rollback method from.